# Which query has better performance?

Tags: query-performance, mysql-5.7, performance-tuning

I have 3 tables as follow:

```
class
  id:bigint(PK)
  name:varchar (unique)


principal:
  id: bigint(PK)
  pid:bigint
  role:boolean
  uniqueConstraint(pid, role)

entry:
  cid: (FK, reference class)
  pid: (FK, refernce principal)
  object_id: bigint
  code: tinyint
  PK: (cid, pid, obj)
```

The query must check existence of a record in `entry` using a parameter set.

suppose parameter set is as follow:

- class's name: Class#3
- principal id as user: 3
- principal id as role: 2
- object ID: 45

I wrote 2 queries, one using *join* and one using *sub-query*, but I don't know which one performs better in large scale production environment:

Query number 1:

```
select id 
from entry 
where pid in ( select id 
               from principal 
               where (pid=2 AND role) 
                  OR (pid=3 AND !role)) 
  AND cid = (select id 
             from class 
             where name='Class#3') 
  AND object_id=45
```

And query number 2:

```
select e.id 
from class c 
inner join entry e on e.cid=c.id 
                  and c.name='Class#3' 
inner join principal p on p.id=e.pid 
                      and p.id in ( select id 
                                    from principal 
                                    where (pid=2 AND role) 
                                       OR (pid=3 AND !role)) 
where e.object_id=45
```

Of course there's an additional condition for checking code which I didn't include it in queries

Suppose there are 100 rows in `class`, 10000 in `principal` and over 250000 in 'entry', and query(as explained) must be executed for each request, and there are 3000 users working on system constantly and simultaneously

1. Which of these queries will perform better And why? the reason is so important for further works
2. Is there better approach to write the query than these 2 approaches or even better approach to construct the schema?

Regards

---

PS: 
I Have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query) about comparing sub-query and join, but my question is not exactly a simple comparison

---

UPDATED: fixed the role column name in `principal` table

Comment: You need to check the query plans and find out.

Comment: Why are you joining to `principal` in the second query?

Comment: @Colin'tHart it's role. I've fixed it. If i don't join principal, how do i achieve the result i want?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually I just know the "explain" keyword of mysql and don't know how to use its results. I'm not a DBA

Comment: In the first instance use EXPLAIN to compare the query plans between the two queries you have. If they are the same then there is no difference. If mysql has `exists` then that may be faster than the two you posed. But you need to compare query plans.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I did that, their execution plans are not the same. I think i have no choice but to put some time and read the mysql documentation. No other way i guess..

Comment: It's an excellent opportunity to deepen your skills. I would happily read doco all day every day and learn new things but I have to do work as well :/. Even just the step of comparing plans starts getting you familiar with them.

Comment: I see that MySQL has `exists` and since you are only after that value of `entry.id`, this _could_ be faster.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have thought about that, but i can't check execution time, cause of mysql caching the queries. after executing them 2-3 times, execution time becomes the same for both queries. I guess i'll have the same problem with using `exists` and comparing its execution time with other approaches

Comment: Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`; it usually performs poorly.  See `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, or `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the simplest way to express the query will perform the best.

The following query should be close to optimal:

```
select e.id
from entry e
join class c on c.id = e.cid 
join principal p on p.id = e.pid
where e.object_id = 45
and c.name = 'Class#3'
and (p.id = 2 and p.role or p.id = 3 and !p.role);
```

But a lot depends on your data and your indexing. Compare execution plans to be sure.

Comment: so you prefer the join over the sub-query. The indexes are stated in question. all columns have unique index, whether individually or in combination with other columns.

Comment: I know the `explain` keyword of _mysql_. But i don't know how to fetch the required information to optimize queries from its result. Unfortunately i'm not  DBA and don't have time to read all the mysql documentation to learn it